# Scala primary constructors and the fields/properties they generate

Tags: scala, constructor

New to Scala and no matter how many articles/tutorials I read (like [these](http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-four-classes-and-constructors/) | [three](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s02.html) | [ones](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-multiple-class-constructors-in-scala-alternate-constructors)) I can't seem to wrap my brain around how constructors work.

Let's take three examples of a primary constructor here:

```
// 1
class Fizz(buzz : Buzz) { ... }

// 2
class Fizz (val buzz : Buzz) { ... }

// 3
class Fizz (var buzz : Buzz) { ... }
```

For each of these:

- Is a `buzz` property created?

  - If so, is it public?
  - Is it mutable?
  - Is is static?
  - Is a getter/setter created for it?
- Is a `buzz` field created?

  - If so, is it public?
  - Is it mutable?
  - Is is static?
  - Is a getter/setter created for it?
- Anything else special/notable about it?

Comment: In Scala there's no such thing as a 'property'. Everything declared with `val` or `var` in a class is an instance member field, everything declared with `def` is an instance method. Everything else is a lexically-scoped variable in the scope of the primary constructor.

Comment: @Yawar, if you declare a constructor parameter and omit using `val` or `var`, the value can still end up being a member field if it is used by an implementation. But no getter will be generated for it though. And there are also compiler generated methods corresponding to the fields in most cases (see my answer).

Comment: @francoisr interesting, thanks for pointing that out! That seems like the implementation detail that enables instance members to 'access' constructor arguments.

Comment: @Yawar Exactly, that what I pointed out in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructors are actually a pretty wild beast in Scala. In fact the Scala compiler is able to make some smart choices for you.

By the phrasing of your question, I take it you probably have some experience with Java. To make it perfectly clear what's happening - and allow you to experiment yourself in the future - let's decompile the code that the Scala compiler produces so we can see the Java equivalent. For conciseness, I'll only show the declarations of the methods/fields, and not their implementation.

### No qualifier, `buzz` used only in constructor

```
class Fizz(buzz : Buzz)
```

Will compile to the Java equivalent of

```
public class Fizz {
    public Fizz(Buzz);
}
```

Since `Fizz` doesn't declare any method/field referencing `buzz` (apart from the constructor itself), Scala will not create any field/method for it.

### No qualifier, `buzz` referenced outside the constructor

```
class Fizz(buzz : Buzz) {
    def foo: Buzz = buzz
}
```

This time `buzz` is used by the `foo` method, and so the compiler has to store it as a field. Since the field was not declared a `var`, it will be made `private final`.

```
public class Fizz {
  private final Buzz buzz;
  public Buzz foo();
  public Fizz(Buzz);
}
```

### `val` qualifier

```
class Fizz(val buzz : Buzz)
```

This time, you explicitly said you wanted `buzz` to be a `val`. This will have the effect of creating a `private final` field to hold `buzz`, and a public method of the same to access it.

```
public class Fizz {
  private final Buzz buzz;
  public Buzz buzz();
  public Fizz(Buzz);
}
```

### `var` qualifier

```
class Fizz(var buzz : Buzz)
```

This case is very similar to the previous one, except that now you're specifying that you want to be able to modify `buzz`. This will cause the Scala compiler to provide a setter method for you, under the funny name of `buzz_$eq`. The `$` shenanigan is only required because of JVM constraints in naming methods. In your Scala code, this method will appear as `buzz_=` and syntactic sugar will allow you to call it as `fizz.buzz = someBuzz`. This way, it actually looks as if you're mutating as field, but you're really only calling a setter.

```
public class Fizz {
  private Buzz buzz;
  public Buzz buzz();
  public void buzz_$eq(Buzz);
  public Fizz(Buzz);
}
```

### How to decompile Scala?

These commands are helpful when investigating that kind of issue:

```
scalac Fizz.scala
```

will create a compiled `Fizz.class` that is not human-readable. You can decompile it into a Java version using

```
javap -constants -p Fizz
```

while in the directory containing `Fizz.class`

Comment: Thanks @francoisr (+1) - everything you say makes sense. Can constructor params be `lazy` as well (so `class Fizz(lazy val buzz : Buzz) { ... }` or `class Fizz(lazy var buzz : Buzz) { ... }`)? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb You can't declare `lazy val`s as constructor parameters, because it would not make much sense from a usage point of view. The `val` would be evaluated upon passing it to the constructor anyway. If what you want is delayed computation of the argument you're passing, you can use a "by-name" parameter instead. For example: `class Foo(bar: => Bar)` will work just fine. In that case, it does not make sense to declare `bar` as a `val` so the compiler won't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

In all the cases you showed the fields are also parameters for the constructor.

The parameters declared to be either val or var become public members. If you use the variables in the constructor they will not become members, if you use them in the class, they will be private members.

In first case `class Fizz(buzz : Buzz){}` the `buzz` parameter is immutable and not become member (I assume you don't use it anywhere).

In second case `class Fizz (val buzz : Buzz) {}` the `buzz` parameter is immutable and become public member.

In third case `class Fizz (var buzz : Buzz) {}` the `buzz` parameter is mutable and become public member.

And again in all the cases there isn't any getter or setter created automatically.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter very much in practice, getters and setters *methods*  are actually created. See my answer.