# What is the default "type" of parameters in scala? Is it Val?

Tags: scala

I have a simple class like this.

I haven't specified whether the parameters are val's or var's. 
What type of parameters are `name` and `price`?

```
 class Car(name:String, price:Float){ 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a class parameter as either `var` or `val`, it will become an instance variable. If you don't specify either, it won't. So it's not equivalent to either `val` or `var`.

In terms of whether or not they can be re-assigned, class parameters act just like normal parameters, which can't be re-assigned.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is right in principle. In practice, however, if the passed parameter is used in the implementation of a `def`, it will become an instance field, acting pretty much as if declared using `private val` (except that no `private def` getter will be generated for it).

For example:

```
class Foo(bar: Bar) {
    def foo: Bar = bar
}
```

can be decompiled into the following java translation (using `javap`)

```
public class Foo {
  private final Bar bar;
  public Bar foo();
  public Foo(Bar);
}
```

See also [my answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877572/scala-primary-constructors-and-the-fields-properties-they-generate/42878477#42878477) for more details about this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by @sepp2k :  If you use a `case class` then the default is `val` :

```
 case class Foo(bar: Bat)
```

in this case `bar` is a `val` that is of `public` accessibility.